# Move a Element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prepend a Font Element in HTML within a DIV. There will be multiple div within the same page with unique Id.

```
<div id="id-unknown">
  "Some Text"
 <font color="red">*</font>
</div>
```

To

```
<div id="id-unknown">
  <font color="red">*</font>
  "Some Text"
</div>
```

I used this Jquery code to achieve it but it gets all the fonts and prepend to every div element

```
$("font").prependTo($("font").parent());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s4Ehw/

Comment: Please don't use the font tag. It's been obsolete for at least 10 years now.

Comment: i have no other option then using font. cos its already used in our platform and i need to use same. i cannot remove it, i can just manipulate it

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do this for specific divs, just add the ID selector and use `.each` to obtain a reference to the specific element (`this`)

```
$('#id1, #id2, #id3').children('font').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```

If it so happens that *every* `font` tag needs this change, use the same `.each` construct as above but use `$('font')`, per your original code and Si Donaldson's answer.

For extra performance, replace the function body with:

```
var parent = this.parentNode;
parent.insertBefore(this, parent.firstChild);
```

i.e. replacing the jQuery calls with direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: there is no need to add an ID. See below for my solution!

Comment: @sidonaldson there is, if `<font>` tags exist in other parts of the document that don't require this treatment.

Comment: no, in that case you add a class to that font tag <font class="addstar">

Comment: Alnitak - well done on editing your answer to match mine. Why have you done this? It's not a competition!

Comment: My answer doesn't match yours, but I did address your comment to account for the case where every `font` tag needs fixing.  My actual code is far more effective than yours, since the original version makes only one call to jQuery for each iteration (yours makes three) and the added version makes none.

Comment: Caching a selector is a very minor change and is not a vast improvement. The fact you have added a lot of information does not mask the fact you have changed your answer to match my solution.
Your first answer basically suggested giving each font an ID and using that directly. That is grossly inefficient in this case.

Comment: you made a comment, I made an edit to address it.  That's how things work around here.  I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: Your original code was:
$('#id-unknown font').each(function() {
        $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
    });
which iterates through each font element within one single id selector. No wonder you edited your answer four times. You were very wrong the first time and now your answer simple mirrors mine but with a lot more words. It's hardly in the spirit of stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to itterate through each one first using $.each and then you can work on each one individually!

http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/s4Ehw/2/

```
$("font").each(function(){
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: NB: `$.each` is not the same as `.each`.

Comment: Alnitak - it is. You can use it inline or you can use $.each([]);

Comment: No, they're not the same function.  Look at the jQuery docs, where they make a distinction between the standalone function `$.each(arg, ...)` and `.each`, which is a method of a jQuery object.

Comment: $.each iterates over an object or an array. You can use it inline via [].each, $().each or you can pass it in as a parameter $.each([]) etc. jQuery selectors just return an array and a reference to themselves(this). off topic though.

Comment: no, look at the difference between http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Alnitak the docs are defining the different uses, the do no define difference in source code. The difference here is that I know how the code works and you don't.

Comment: ah, resorting to ad hominem attacks, now then?  I know perfectly well how the code works, having written numerous jQuery plugins.  It happens that `.each` is just a wrapper for `$.each`, but all I was trying to do was point out that writing the latter when using the former is incorrect.

Comment: I calmly replied and you continued to attempt to troll me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're the one trolling me...  The fact is, the two are _not_ interchangeable.  `.each` is a specialisation of `$.each` that only works on jQuery objects, whereas the latter works on any array-like object.

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/s4Ehw/8/

It's interchangeable. Let's leave this here.

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery each function for manage elements in cycle
jsfiddle.net/s4Ehw/6/

```
$("font").each(function(){
  $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($("font"), function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element));
    $(element).prependTo($(element).parent());
});
```